# Can't get the value from doInBackGround() process at onPostExecute()

Tags: java, android

I'm using `AsyncTask` to insert, update and delete data from database. I used this code to insert, update, delete and it works fine. But when I want to use select, and show the data at `EditText`, I can't get the value from `doInBackground()` to the `onPostExecute()` and it shows nothing.

Here's my code :

MenuUtama.java

```
public class MenuUtama extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */ 
    private TextView nama_user;
    private String nm_user = "";
    private EditText kode, nama, harga, deskripsi; 
    private Button insert, update, delete, cek; 
    private String kode1, nama1, harga1, deskripsi1; 
    JSONArray data = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        kode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editKode); 
        nama = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editNama); 
        harga = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editHarga); 
        deskripsi = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editDes); 
        cek = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCek);
        insert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonInsert); 
        update = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpdate); 
        delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete); 
        nama_user = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        nm_user = i.getStringExtra("nama_user"); 
        nama_user.setText(nm_user);


        insert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

                String url = "";
                url = "http://192.168.1.10/crudsederhana/aksi.php";

                try {
                    String ko = URLEncoder.encode(kode.getText().toString(),"utf-8");
                    String n = URLEncoder.encode(nama.getText().toString(),"utf-8"); 
                    String hr = URLEncoder.encode(harga.getText().toString(),"utf-8");
                    String d = URLEncoder.encode(deskripsi.getText().toString(), "utf-8");

                    url += "?a=insert&kd=" + ko + "&nm=" + n + "&hrg=" + hr + "&deskripsi=" + d;

                    new CRUD().execute(url);
                }

                catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) { 
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        update.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) { 
                String url = "";

                url = "http://192.168.1.10/crudsederhana/aksi.php";

                try { 
                    String ko = URLEncoder.encode(kode.getText().toString(),"utf-8");
                    String n = URLEncoder.encode(nama.getText().toString(),"utf-8");
                    String hr = URLEncoder.encode(harga.getText().toString(),"utf-8");
                    String d = URLEncoder.encode(deskripsi.getText().toString(), "utf-8");

                    url += "?a=update&kd=" + ko + "&nm=" + n + "&hrg=" +hr+ "&des=" + d;

                    new CRUD().execute(url);
                } 

                catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) { 
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                String url = "";
                kode1 = kode.getText().toString(); 
                url = "http://192.168.1.10/crudsederhana/aksi.php?a=delete&kd=" + kode1;

                new CRUD().execute(url);
            }
        });

        cek.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                String url = "";
                kode1 = kode.getText().toString();
                url = "http://192.168.1.10/crudsederhana/aksi.php?a=read&kd="+kode1;

                new CRUD().execute(url);
            }
        });
    }

    public class CRUD extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> { 
        String success;
        String kode_d, nama_d, harga_d, des_d;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() { 
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser(); 
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(params[0]);

            try {
                success = json.getString("success"); 
                Log.e("error", "nilai sukses=" + success); 
                JSONArray hasil = json.getJSONArray("login"); 

                if (success.equals("1")) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < hasil.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = hasil.getJSONObject(i);

                        kode_d = c.getString("kd"); 
                        nama_d = c.getString("nm"); 
                        harga_d = c.getString("hrg"); 
                        des_d = c.getString("deskripsi");
                    }
                }

                else {
                    Log.e("erro", "tidak bisa ambil data 0");
                }
            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Log.e("erro", "tidak bisa ambil data 1");
            }

            return kode_d;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            kode.setText(kode_d); 
            nama.setText(nama_d); 
            harga.setText(harga_d); 
            deskripsi.setText(des_d);
        }
    }
}
```

JSONParser.java

```
public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream is = null; 
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    //  constructor 
    public JSONParser() {
    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
        // Making HTTP request 
        try {

            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost); 
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }

        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        catch (ClientProtocolException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " +e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object 
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        }

        catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " +e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String 
        return jObj;
    }

    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request 
        try {
            // check for request method 
            if (method == "POST") {

                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient 
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url); 
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params)); 
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity(); 
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

            else if (method == "GET") {
                // request method is GET 
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8"); 
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url); 
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity(); 
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }
        }

        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        catch (ClientProtocolException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        catch (IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " +e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object 
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        }

        catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " +e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String 
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have tried debugging or print log? Do you get values in string?

Comment: `I can't get the value from doInBackground() ` You are  not even trying to get the return value of doInBackground(). And doInBackground is allways returning null. So how would onPostExecute know if all went wrong or if there was an exception. Start with letting doInBackground return valid strings and examine what you get in onPostExecute in parameter String result.

Comment: I already trying to return the value like "kode_d", but in onPostExecute() still not show anything in the EditText

Comment: You are losing exception in this block: `Log.e("erro", "tidak bisa ambil data 1")`. Log `e` here, and you will discover what is wrong with your code.
            }

Answer (score 0):

It is because you don't return any value from the `doInBackground()` (always return null) and you are not using the 'string' in the `onPostExecute(String result)` formal parameter. Garbage-In-Garbage-Out

Comment: I already trying to return the value like "kode_d", but in onPostExecute() still not show anything in the EditText. In my code I already used the formal paramater "protected void onPostExecute(String result)"

Comment: The value that you return in `doInBackground()` is what will be in the formal parameter of `onPostExecute(String result)` . So, as you've returned `kode_d`, I would assume that is what you want to be in `kode`, so it would be something like  `kode.setText(result);`

Comment: I already return kode_d from the `kode_d = c.getString("kd");` at the `doInBackground()` process, but in `kode.setText(result);` it still shows nothing

Answer (score 0):

your `doInBackground()` returns just a string `return kode_d;` and then in your `onPostExecute(String result)` (which expects a String) you use the kode_d which is null.

If you want all of those values to be returned create an `ArrayList()`, return it at the end `doInBackground()` and get it in `onPostExecute(ArrayList result)` with an iteration and pass it to you textviews.

Even better create an object and add the values to each field. Your fields are the `kode_d, nama_d, harga_d, des_d`

this is what the onPostExecute does

```
/**
 * <p>Runs on the UI thread after {@link #doInBackground}. The
 * specified result is the value returned by {@link #doInBackground}.
 * To better support testing frameworks, it is recommended that this be
 * written to tolerate direct execution as part of the execute() call.
 * The default version does nothing.</p>
 * 
 * <p>This method won't be invoked if the task was cancelled.</p>
 *
 * @param result The result of the operation computed by {@link #doInBackground}.
 *
 * @see #onPreExecute
 * @see #doInBackground
 * @see #onCancelled(Object) 
 */
```

Comment: I already create an `ArrayList()` like this `List<String> LIST = new ArrayList<String>();` and I add the string to the array list using `LIST.add(c.getString("kd"));` and `return LIST`, after that, on `onPostExecute` I want to retrieve the array list using `String a = result.get(0);` And I use Toast to show the retrieved array list like this `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), a, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` but it comes to an error and it says `IndexOutofBoundsException: Index:0, Size:0)` even though I already add the string to an Array List, the array list still 0

Comment: You need to debug. Is your url right? Log your steps, or use the debug functionality in Android Studio. You are getting an empty list and you need to find why in the previous steps.